# Как правильно делать сдвиг содержимого массива?

Tags: массивы, c, указатели, macos

Решил освежить свои знание по Си и сразу, как не странно, встретил проблему с указателями. 
Этот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char str[80], *p = NULL;
    strcpy(str, "Когда, в случае если...");
    p = str + 10;
    printf("p = %s\n", p);

    return 0;
}
```

выводит:

> p = , в случае если...

Но я был уверен, что результатом будет:

> p = лучае если...

Почему так происходит?

Comment: У Вас наверняка кодировка utf-8. А там *все русские буковки* по 2 байта занимают.

Автор, в подобных вопросах еще и какая ОС надо бы писать...

Answer (score 2):

Да просто ваша строка в мультибайтовой кодировке, в которой некоторые символы занимают по два байта, а char как известно занимает 1 байт в памяти. Вы сдвигаете указатель на 10 элементов вперед, но в вашем случае 10 элементов != 10 символам. Попробуйте вывести strlen(src), я думаю вы не увидите ожидаемые вами 23

```
_mbstrlen(str) должна выдать 23
strlen(str) по идее больше
```

Я так понимаю вы тестируете этот код на линуксе???

Comment: в Виндовой консоли ваш код (без изменений и танцев с бубеами) выведет вместо текста крякозябры, но зато в том количестве, которое вы ожидаете.

Comment: Возможно для винды этого достаточно, а в линуксе используйте `mblen()`.

Только `setlocale()` (и \#include <locale.h>) надо к программе добавить.

Comment: strlen(str) показал 39 байт. А что за функция _mbstrlen()? Это из Си?

Comment: Да из C. доступна из <stdlib.h> по крайней мере для Visual Studio, с другими компиляторами для С дел не имел, как и с Линуксом в чистом виде

Comment: С Маком не знаком, но попробуйте

    #include <locale.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int 
    mbstrlen(const char *s)
    {
      int l, ofs = 0, n = 0;
    
      while ((l = mblen(s + ofs, 8)) > 0) {
        ofs += l; n++;
      }
      return n;
    }
    
    int main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, ""); // default locale
        ....
    }

может у Вас тоже будет работать

Answer (score 0):

Это сдвиг указателя, но не массива.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char str[80], *p = NULL;
    const char *src = "Когда, в случае если...";
    int offset = 10;
// Копируем, начиная с offset
    strcpy(str, &src[offset]);
    printf("str = %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

ЗЫ Пишу почти на бегу, если что, не серчайте =)

ЗЫЫ sizeof('s') != sizeof('ю'). Сдвигаетесь вы слишком энергично =)
http://ideone.com/XoqhK0

Comment: @Free_ze, пример на идеоне не соответствует данным у ТС.

wchar_t у него **вообще нет**. Только строка, наверняка с utf-8.